# Strategy, State, Singleton... or a Composition thereof?

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton, strategy-pattern, state-pattern

I am new on stackoverflow and relatively new to WPF.

I've wrapped my head around a half dozen weighty tomes of Patterns and Best Practices (as well as numerous posts here) but cannot seem to find the solution I am looking for.

My Problem: WPF / .Net 4 / C#
I have a text processor (of type **Editor E**) that can load one Document (of type **Document D**) at a time (strored as **Editor.CurrentDocument**). Several UI controls bind to the **Document**'s properties (all Dependency Properties) such as **Document.Title**, **Document.DateLastModification**.

Now I want to be able to switch the actual Document instance without having to unhook and re-hook all event handlers. So I guess the Editor.CurrentDocument property must somehow remain its instance while switching its implementation.

I have tried to create a **SingleInstanceDocument** class that inherits directly from Document and uses the Singleton pattern. But then I cannot find a way to inject any Document instance into the SingleInstanceDocument without having to internally re-map all properties.

Am I somehow being misguided or missing the point here? If the SingleInstanceDocument approach is a viable solution, is there any way I can use reflection to re-map all available dependency properties from the inner Document to the outer SingleInstanceDocument shell automatically?

Thank you very much!

**Addendum**:

It turned out that the functionality required here was already provided by WPF/.NET out of the box by implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged** on the CurrentDocument host object. Thus changing the current document caused the UI to update its bound controls appropriately. I'm sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: Time to do some forgetting. Patterns are about getting things done, not about serving the right patterns. What would be the gain of having a 'SingleInstanceDocument'? Can't you just instantiate only one?

Comment: The thing is my application uses an ORM so that all Documents are already loaded when the Editor starts. I just want to switch the currently edited Document in the Editor with any one of the instances already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, learn some basic MVVM pattern. basically in WPF-MVVM just use ObservableCollection and [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

this type of collection implements the observer pattern that notify update to UI(View) when you add/remove or "select" the current item.

```
//in main ViewModel
private Ducument _currentDocument;

public Document CurrentDocument 
{ 
    get { return _currentDocument; }
    set
    {
        _currentDocument = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentDocument");
    }
}

//stored all loaded documents as collection.
public ObservableCollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
```

binding selected - current item.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Documents}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentDocument}" DisplayMemberPath="Title">
    <!-- //all Document.Title as listitem -->
</ListBox>
<!--// Editor's View -->
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=CurrentDocument}"></ContentControl>
```